# How to count API Calls authenticated by OAuth2

Tags: mysql, oauth-2.0, api-design

I am offering a Restful API to clients that access it by webservice. Now I would like to be able to count the API call per month.

What would be the best way to count the calls? Incrmenting a DB field would mean on DB call more. Is there a workaround? We are talking about millions of API calls per month.

Answer (score 0):

You can also log to text file and use log analytics tools such as Webalizer(http://www.webalizer.org/) to analyze the text files

HTH

Comment: that is unfortunatelly not possible as the api call is always the same and does not differ on per client basis. The client_id is passed by post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate in-memory database to track these values, and write them to disk occasionally. Or store calls in a collection and batch-write them to the database occasionally.

Comment: that sounds like a plan! Could I also use a in memory table and write the contents of a table every 60s to a fixed memory table? Do you have any recommendations on what to look after? I would create the in memory table, and a cron job that does the storage transfer every 60s.

Comment: @merlin if it's just counting the calls, and you can tolerate your number being off if the server crashes, just use a Map<ClientId, Count> to keep track of the hits, and then write to the DB from that.  An in-memory DB would be overkill. If the set of data you want to keep is more complex, then yeah, an IMDB is the way to go. Unfortunately, I can't give you any good recommendations as to an implementation. :-( I know java ships with Derby, but I can't attest to its quality. If you're using EHCache or Hibernate, they may also have options. I'm afraid you're going to have to do some research. :(

Comment: What do you mean by "Map"? I could not find any exmple in relation to mysql.

Comment: I meant a java.util.Map storing the data on the business tier. For database-tier storage in MySQL, you can use the [MEMORY Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

Comment: I understand. But isn't creating a table of the type "memory" the same?

Comment: I can't say. I'm not a MySQL expert. :-)